# How to create a data set that can be loaded using load datasetname command in Matlab?

Tags: machine-learning, matlab

I am trying to create a data set with multi class data and labels. I am able to load data from a file and get it classified as multiple variables. I saved the code as 'multiclass.m'. Then when I use the load command,

> > load multiclass

I get the error

??? Error using ==> load
Unable to read file multiclass: No such file or directory.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I load the data set from a different file?

Answer (score 1):

Try saving as `multiclass.mat` rather than `multiclass.m`. '.m' files are MATLAB script files, which hold functions and scripts and other code, while '.mat' files are matlab data files, which store MATLAB variables.

Comment: one should add, that if you just leave out the file-extension when saving, the extension will be .mat by default. if you use another extension, what can be useful if you want to show that the data is some kind of special structure for example, you can still load it with the additional parameter: load('myFile.qwe','_mat')